# Do I have Kotlin stdlib twice?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In Android Studio 3
gradle ->  --> Tasks --> android --> androidDependecies:

```
> Task :app:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21@jar
....
```

In my app module build.gradle I have:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

Furtheron, I also found:

```
debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01@aar
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21@jar
+--- :a_lib
+--- com.github.nisrulz:qreader:2.1.2@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.20@jar
...
```

Q1: How can I find out where the second kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 comes from? Possibly from a third party lib?

Q2: As you can see, Kotlin 1.3.21 and 1.3.20 was used. I bet the 1.3.20 comes with another lib and this can cause future problems?

Comment: You have `-jdk7` both for compilation and for runtime, and `-jdk8` both for compilation and for runtime. Since they are indeed needed for both, what is the problem?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Didn't know both were needed. Looks redundant.

Comment: Both `-jdk7` and `-jdk8` or both compilation and runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [its pom](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/jar), `-jdk8` depends on both `-jdk7` and `kotlin-stdlib`, that's why you see both. The `-jdk*` artefacts only contain JDK 7 and JDK 8 specific features/extensions and do not cause the whole JDK to be imported twice.

From the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies):

> There are extended versions of the standard library that add support for some of the features of JDK 7 and JDK 8

To answer Q2, that dependancy comes from another dependancy. You should be able to find out where it is imported from by running `gradle dependencies`.